# Gitlab 6.9.2 access denied for deploy key

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to clone repository via SSH. Public key for my user is set as deploy key in a project.

I got this error message:

```
Access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Here is my /var/log/secure for this attempt

```
Jul 16 11:09:54 gitlab sshd[32217]: Accepted publickey for git from <IP> port 55499 ssh2
Jul 16 11:09:54 gitlab sshd[32217]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=0)
Jul 16 11:09:54 gitlab sshd[32219]: Received disconnect from <IP>: 11: disconnected by user
Jul 16 11:09:54 gitlab sshd[32217]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user git
```

And here is /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log

```
[2014-07-16T11:09:54.407037 #32220] ERROR -- : API call <GET https://gitlab//api/v3/internal/allowed?action=git-upload-pack&ref=_any&project=group%2Fproject&forced_push=false&key_id=5> failed: 404 => <{"message":"404 Not found"}>.W,
[2014-07-16T11:09:54.407161 #32220]  WARN -- : gitlab-shell: Access denied for git command <git-upload-pack 'group/project.git'> by user with key key-5.
```

Can you please help me to figure out what's wrong?

For many other deploy keys specified everything works just well.

Answer (score 0):

Today I run into the same behavior as you describe. I found an open issue in gitlabhq(https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6908).

The problem is that it can happen that the same public key are two times listed in `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`. In my case I deleted the deploy key and recreate it to have a better name. In this case the key was not remove from the `authorized_keys` file.

After I deleted the deploy key and the corresponding lines in the `authorized_keys` file and recreate the deploy key in my project the access is working.